# How do I run a Python Script in PowerBI?

Tags: python, powerbi, bar-chart

I am new to Python. I am trying to create a Bar Chart in Power BI using Python but the script does not seem to work. The code is below:

```
pip install pandas
pip install matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(dataset.Letter,dataset.Number)
plt.show()
```

Please find attached the file:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/f0bwt9cp4ha1sfb/Example.pbix/file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqfNA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing only one (1) initial time `pip install pandas` and `pip install matplotlib`, you only need to write in your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset.plot('bar', dataset.Letter, dataset.Number)
plt.show()
```

`import` is for setting up the library and you must always use it in your code, while pip install pandas and pip install matplotlib only need to be installed once at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be required to run pip install every time you run your script. You should only have to use pip install commands when installing a library for the first time. This might require you ensuring that you have the correct libraries located on your computer. However, I do not know what your error is since I do not have your error code.

Also, be sure to specify what type of plot you wish to produce from matplotlob.

Try (EDIT):

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    dataset.plot(kind='bar', x='Letter', y='Number')
    plt.show()
```

You do not need an indent in your last two lines of code.

Also after reviewing you update I think it might be best if yo review the matplotlib library documentation and familiarize yourself with Python basics. You can learn Python almost anywhere, I have found the interactive lessons on w3schools.com to be useful.

matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/index.html